# Ignoring formatting while importing to xls using CasperJS

Tags: excel, import, casperjs

I have a script in casperJS that scrapes data from a webpage, then puts that information into a variable

```
var lbdes = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="product_overview"]'));
```

and I call that variable using FS to create an excel doc.

```
casper.then(function() {
var f = fs.open('scrapetest.xls', 'w');
f.write(lbdes);
f.close();
});
```

Problem is, when that variable imports into excel it looks like the image below -- Ideally I would love to keep that formatting but somehow force that string to stay in 1 cell rather than spanning across 3+ rows and 3+ columns.

[image]

Comment: You need to show what the value of `lbdes` is. Why do you want to export it to xls if you only want it to be in a single cell? Just write it to a text file.

Comment: Because I export many other variables into xls at the same time as this one, I then cut and paste each group of variables into a different column so I can then upload this xls document as a product feed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without writing an xls exporter in js. I'm surprised the naive approach works so well. I would have expected a broken document. You should probably use CSV since it is an extremely simple text format.